# Pretty display of a sentence and its grammatical dependencies

Tags: python, nltk, stanford-nlp, graphviz

Does anyone knows how to display a sentence with its dependencies like that: [image: prettyprnt dependencies]
I am using StanfordDependencyParser in NLTK to get the dependencies and am able to display a tree representation with Graphviz:

```
from nltk.parse import stanford
from graphviz import Source
sdp = stanford.StanfordDependencyParser('path/to/stanford-parser-3.9.1-models.jar', corenlp_options=('-retainTmpSubcategories', '-originalDependencies', '-outputFormatOptions', 'typedDependenciesCollapsed'))

p = sdp.raw_parse(sent)
dot = Source(next(p).to_dot())
dot.view()
```

but can't figure out how to keep the original sentence and have the edges going from one word to another.

Comment: Please post the code you are using to generate the tree representation. It may help someone here (a Graphwiz?) find a solution.

Comment: Thanks, I added the code.

Answer (score 0):

These were generated using the [Brat annotation tool](http://brat.nlplab.org/), which is a JS library to render either token annotations or these sorts of dependency tree annotations.

You can look at the [source code](https://github.com/stanfordnlp/CoreNLP/blob/ba89b0781bf22793f6679ed52ff8367898b23d90/src/edu/stanford/nlp/pipeline/demo/corenlp-brat.js) of corenlp.run for an example of how to use the tool. For example, [this section](https://github.com/stanfordnlp/CoreNLP/blob/ba89b0781bf22793f6679ed52ff8367898b23d90/src/edu/stanford/nlp/pipeline/demo/corenlp-brat.js#L475) for dependency trees.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an approximation using Graphviz - kind of close, if you squint. It uses one "html" table per word.

```
digraph s1 {
  graph [nodesep=.01]
  node [shape=plaintext]
  {
  rank=same
  s1 [ordering=out label=1]
  edge [style=invis]

  s1->w10 
  s1->w9
  s1->w8
  s1->w7
  s1->w6
  s1->w5
  s1->w4
  s1->w3
  s1->w2
  s1->w1
  edge [style=""]  
  w1 [label=<
    <TABLE BORDER="0" CELLBORDER="1" CELLSPACING="0">
      <TR><TD BGCOLOR="lavender">PRP</TD></TR>
      <TR><TD BORDER="0">We</TD></TR>
   </TABLE>>]
  w2 [shape=plaintext  label=<   
   <TABLE BORDER="0" CELLBORDER="1" CELLSPACING="0">
      <TR><TD BGCOLOR="green1">PRP</TD></TR>
      <TR ><TD BORDER="0">are</TD></TR>
   </TABLE>>]
  w3 [shape=plaintext  label=<   
   <TABLE BORDER="0" CELLBORDER="1" CELLSPACING="0">
      <TR><TD BGCOLOR="green1">PRP</TD></TR>
      <TR ><TD BORDER="0">facing</TD></TR>
   </TABLE>>]   
  w4 [shape=plaintext  label=<
   <TABLE BORDER="0" CELLBORDER="1" CELLSPACING="0">
      <TR><TD BGCOLOR="lavender">PRP</TD></TR>
      <TR><TD BORDER="0">a</TD></TR>
   </TABLE>>]

  w5 [shape=plaintext  label=<
   <TABLE BORDER="0" CELLBORDER="1" CELLSPACING="0">
      <TR><TD BGCOLOR="lavender">PRP</TD></TR>
      <TR><TD BORDER="0">failure</TD></TR>
   </TABLE>>]
  w6 [shape=plaintext  label=<
   <TABLE BORDER="0" CELLBORDER="1" CELLSPACING="0">
      <TR><TD BGCOLOR="lavender">PRP</TD></TR>
      <TR><TD BORDER="0">when</TD></TR>
   </TABLE>>]
  w7 [shape=plaintext  label=<
   <TABLE BORDER="0" CELLBORDER="1" CELLSPACING="0">
      <TR><TD BGCOLOR="lavender">PRP</TD></TR>
      <TR><TD BORDER="0">running</TD></TR>
   </TABLE>>]
  w8 [shape=plaintext  label=<
   <TABLE BORDER="0" CELLBORDER="1" CELLSPACING="0">
      <TR><TD BGCOLOR="lavender">VBG</TD></TR>
      <TR><TD BORDER="0">xyz</TD></TR>
   </TABLE>>]
  w9 [shape=plaintext  label=<
   <TABLE BORDER="0" CELLBORDER="1" CELLSPACING="0">
      <TR><TD BGCOLOR="lavender">NN</TD></TR>
      <TR><TD BORDER="0">job</TD></TR>
   </TABLE>>]
  w10 [shape=plaintext  label=<
   <TABLE BORDER="0" CELLBORDER="1" CELLSPACING="0">
      <TR><TD BGCOLOR="lavender">.</TD></TR>
      <TR><TD BORDER="0">.</TD></TR>
   </TABLE>>]

   edge[constraint=false]
   w3->w2 [label="\naux"]
   w3->w1 [label="\nblah 1"]
   w3:ne->w5 [label="\nblah 2"]
   w3:ne->w7 [label="\nblah 3"]
   w3:n->w10 [label="\nblah 4"]
   }
}
```

Giving this:
[image]